# Stars and bars with at least 1 group of 2 adjacent bars

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to figure out the number of $n$ permutations for $N$ stars and $K \ge{2}$ bars such that there is at least 1 group of 2 adjacent bars.

For example, in this trivial example $N = 1$ and $K = 3$ then $n = 4$

$|||* \\ ||*| \\ |*|| \\ *|||$

This coincides with your typical counting argument $\frac{4!}{3!1!}$. However, for a more non-trivial example where $N = 2$ and $K = 3$, we have $n = 9$.

My initial instinct was to group the 2 bars as a "group" and permute it with the rest of the stars and bars (so for $N = 2$ and $K = 3$, we have $\frac{4!}{1!1!2!} = 12 \ne 9$).

The only counting argument I can come up with is to find the total # of permutations and subtract the # of permutations where there are no adjacent bars ($\frac{5!}{3!2!} - 1 = 9$), but this would involve tedious case work with groups of $*|*$ for the # of perms without adjacent bars. Clearly this does not work when $K > 2N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: It’s probably easiest to count the arrangements that do *not* have two adjacent bars and subtract from $\binom{N+K}N$, the total number of possible arrangements.

If there are no adjacent bars, of course, we must have $K\ge N-1$. Put one star in each slot between adjacent bars; that leaves $K-(N-1)=K-N+1$ stars to be distributed arbitrarily amongst the $N+1$ possible slots (including the two end slots).

Answer (score 0):

think of it as selecting $k$ objects out of $n+k$ such that no two are consecutive.

This can be done in $\binom{n+1}{k}$ ways. ([See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067936/number-of-ways-to-choose-6-books-out-of-20-books-such-that-no-2-are-adjacent-boo/1067965#1067965) )

So the answer is $\binom{n+k}{k}-\binom{n+1}{k}$

Comment: Do you mean $\binom{n+1}{k - (n-1)}$?

Comment: they are equal, remember that $\binom{x}{y}=\binom{x}{x-y}$